# Django - Delete File After FileField Delete

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project which in i use file field to upload files.

What i want to do is to delete the file field's file which is linked to the object im trying to delete.

I used This document as an example: 
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10638/

when i use these functions i get the dollowing error on the server: 
"Error 32 - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" 
I think that the process which uses it is the django server because i tried to delete it with a regular python script (same functions) and with batch and it worked just fine.

Anyone knows a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to delete files (FileField, ImageField) when whole model is deleted ?

Try like this.

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model)
    ''' for example this is your model '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/test/var/')

# this is your view
mm = MyModel.objects.get(pk=111)
# print(mm.image)
mm.image.close() # add this line
mm.image.delete() # this will delete file and not model
```

Comment: no, i want to delete the file which the object is linked to**

Comment: I updated my answer, check it. Does not matter . FileField is super class of ImageField.

Comment: I get the same error: Error 32 - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: See my last update. Restart server also. Hope this fix your problem.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was so hard for me to find but I'm glad I found it!